# Is File Sharing Allowed?

Tags: halacha, internet, intellectual-property

Are we permitted to share files via file distrubution systems on the internet? For example, using Torrent files to get movies, songs or software?

Comment: copyrighted files? to download or upload?

Comment: Yes, for download and usually also upload (e.g. seeding).

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/copying-various-forms-of-media http://www.jpost.com/Opinion/Columnists/Ask-the-Rabbi-May-one-share-music-or-videos-on-the-Internet-321060